# How to scroll to the particular unique URL using selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Storing Url in the String variable
        String url = "Target URL ";
        // Launch
        driver.get(url);
        // List Of URL
        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println("Total Count:" + links.size());
        Iterator<WebElement> it = links.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            url = it.next().getAttribute("href");

            System.out.println(url);

        }

    }
}
```

How to scroll to the particular single URL and click it using selenium?

Comment: use the bobble sorting method

Comment: wanted to avoid repeated URL .

Comment: What's your goal here? Are you trying to validate that there's no broken links?

Comment: Trying to fetch Distinct  URL

Answer (score 1):

Create a `HashSet<String>` and put all your URLs there. After you have added the last URL you will be having only unique set in your `HashSet`.

```
import java.util.*;
// .. some other imports here
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Storing Url in the String variable
    String url = "Target URL ";
    // Launch
    driver.get(url);
    // List Of URL
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println("Total Count:" + links.size());
    // Create hashset
    HashSet<String> uniqueURLs = new HashSet<String>();
    // Add all your elements to hashset
    for(WebElement link: links){
        uniqueURLs.add(link.getAttribute("href"));
    }
    for (String urlUniqueItem: new ArrayList<String>(uniqueURLs)) {
        System.out.println(urlUniqueItem);
    }
}
```

`HashSet` do not store object duplicates so that you can be sure after you have added all the objects there would no be duplicates.

Comment: It's giving an error at line  HashSet

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: HashSet cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Import it from java.util package

Comment: uniqueURLs.add(link.getAttribute("href"));Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method add(String) is undefined for the type HashSet<String>
 The method iterator() is undefined for the type HashSet<String>

Comment: @SayaliJoglekar check now

Comment: for (String url: new ArrayList<String>(uniqueURLs)) {                 
 for this giving an error Duplicate local variable url   if i change the name it giving same above error

Comment: Fixed. Renamed url to urlUniqueItem in for clause

Comment: uniqueURLs.add(link.getAttribute("href"));Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method add(String) is undefined for the type HashSet<String>
 The constructor ArrayList<String>(HashSet<String>) is undefined
same Error :(

Comment: Make sure you're making proper imports. See my updates

Comment: import java.util.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; all import done

Comment: This is kind of magic. Make sure you have JDK bound to your project in your IDE.